# Reading directly to struct in C++

Tags: c++, cin

Let's say I have some structure, for example a `Rectangle`:

```
struct Rectangle
{
    int x0, x1, y0, y1;
};
```

Is it possible to create a Rectangle struct in a way to be able to just call:

```
Rectangle rec;
cin >> rec;
```

? I think it should be possible to make it somehow, but I am not experienced enough.

**Disclaimer**

I am not looking for this:

```
cin >> rec.x0 >> rec.x1 >> rec.y0 >> rec.y1;
```

Comment: Overload operator `>>` in your class?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use:

```
Rectangle rec;
cin >> rec;
```

if you define an appropriate `operator>>` function.

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Rectangle& rec)
{
   return (in >> rec.x0 >> rec.x1 >> rec.y0 >> rec.y1);
}
```

If you are not allowed to define such a function, then you cannot use the syntax you want to use.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the best solution is to overload `operator>>` for `Rectangle`:

```
struct Rectangle
{
    int x0, x1, y0, y1;
};

istream& operator>>(istream& s, Rectangle& r)
{
    s >> r.x0 >> r.x1 >> r.y0 >> r.y1;
    return s;
}
```

Comment: r doesnt have members x, y and z tho